# Angular v6 mat-table doesn't show information in view but does in console

Tags: angular, angular-material

I wrote an Angular data table and works well but just doesnt show the information in the view:

[image: Row with no content]

Then, I defined a function for show the information on console when clicked on a row. And the result is below:

[image: Clicked row shows information on console]

Well, you noticed that maybe DataSource works well but view doens rendered the information.

Here's the views code:

```
<div class="course">

<mat-icon>search</mat-icon>

<mat-form-field>

    <input matInput placeholder="Search lessons" #input>

</mat-form-field>

<div class="spinner-container" *ngIf="ListadoData.Cargando | async">

    <mat-spinner></mat-spinner>

</div>

<mat-table class="lessons-table mat-elevation-z8" [dataSource]="ListadoData"
           matSort matSortActive="seqNo" matSortDirection="asc" matSortDisableClear>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="seqNo">

        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>#</mat-header-cell>

        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let user">{{user.seqNo}}</mat-cell>

    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="description">

        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Description</mat-header-cell>

        <mat-cell class="description-cell"
                  *matCellDef="let lesson">{{lesson.description}}</mat-cell>

    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="duration">

        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Duration</mat-header-cell>

        <mat-cell class="duration-cell"
                  *matCellDef="let lesson">{{lesson.duration}}</mat-cell>

    </ng-container>

    <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>

    <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns" (click)="FilaClick(row)"></mat-row>

</mat-table>


<mat-paginator [length]="course?.lessonsCount" [pageSize]="10"
               [pageSizeOptions]="[3, 5, 10]"></mat-paginator>
```

Here is the component:

```
          import {AfterViewInit, Component, ElementRef, OnInit, ViewChild} from '@angular/core';
      import {ListadoDataSource} from './listado.data.service';
      import {ListadoService} from './listado.service';
      import {ActivatedRoute} from "@angular/router";
      import {MatPaginator, MatSort, MatTableDataSource} from "@angular/material";
      import {Course} from './course.models'
      import {debounceTime, distinctUntilChanged, startWith, tap, delay} from 'rxjs/operators';
      import {map} from 'rxjs/operators'
      import {merge} from "rxjs/operators";
      import {fromEvent} from 'rxjs';

      @Component({
        selector: 'app-listado',
        templateUrl: './listado.component.html',
        styleUrls: ['./listado.component.css']
      })
      export class ListadoComponent implements OnInit {

        course:Course;
        ListadoData: ListadoDataSource;
        displayedColumns: ['seqNo', 'description', 'duration'];

        @ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator: MatPaginator;
        @ViewChild(MatSort) sort: MatSort;
        @ViewChild('input') input: ElementRef;

        constructor(private ListadoService: ListadoService, private route: ActivatedRoute) { }

        ngOnInit() {
        /*  this.course = this.route.snapshot.data["course"];*/
          this.ListadoData = new ListadoDataSource(this.ListadoService);
          this.ListadoData.CargarLecciones(1, '', 'asc', 0, 10);
        }

        ngAfterViewInit() {

            this.sort.sortChange.subscribe(() => this.paginator.pageIndex = 0);

            fromEvent(this.input.nativeElement,'keyup')
                .pipe(
                    debounceTime(150),
                    distinctUntilChanged(),
                    tap(() => {
                        this.paginator.pageIndex = 0;

                        this.CargarLeccionesPagina();
                    })
                )
                .subscribe();

            this.paginator.page
            .pipe(
                tap(() => this.CargarLeccionesPagina())
            )
            .subscribe();

            this.sort.sortChange
            .pipe(
                tap(() => this.CargarLeccionesPagina())
            )
            .subscribe();
        }

        CargarLeccionesPagina(){
          this.ListadoData.CargarLecciones(
            1,
            this.input.nativeElement.value,
            this.sort.direction,
            this.paginator.pageIndex,
            this.paginator.pageSize
          );
        }

        FilaClick(row){
          console.log(row)
        }
      }
```

And the DataSource:

```
        import {CollectionViewer, DataSource} from "@angular/cdk/collections";
    import {Lesson} from './listado.models';
    import {BehaviorSubject, Observable} from "rxjs";
    import {ListadoService} from './listado.service';
    import {catchError, finalize} from "rxjs/operators";
    import {of} from "rxjs";

    export class ListadoDataSource implements DataSource<Lesson>{

      private ComportamientoLeccion = new BehaviorSubject<Lesson[]>([]);
      private CargandoLeccion = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);

      public Cargando = this.CargandoLeccion.asObservable();

      constructor(private ListadoService: ListadoService){ }

      connect (collectionViewer: CollectionViewer):Observable<Lesson[]>{
        return this.ComportamientoLeccion.asObservable();
      }

      disconnect(collectionViewer: CollectionViewer): void{
        this.ComportamientoLeccion.complete();
        this.CargandoLeccion.complete()
      }

      CargarLecciones(
        courseId:number,
        filter= '',
        sortDirection='asc',
        pageIndex=0,
        pageSize=10
      ){
        this.CargandoLeccion.next(true);

        this.ListadoService.ObtenerLecciones(courseId, filter, sortDirection, pageIndex, pageSize)
          .pipe(catchError(()=>of([])),
          finalize(()=>this.CargandoLeccion.next(false))
        )
        .subscribe(lecciones => this.ComportamientoLeccion.next(lecciones));
      }

    }
```

Ill be very thankfully for your help.

Thank you very much!

Comment: can you create a stackblitz to show your problem

Answer (score 0):

Try using row instead of user, lesson, etc.  At least at one time we had to use row but I see in the docs they sometimes use 'element'.  It must be the same for all rows.

```
*matCellDef="let row"> {{row.description}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, found it search in every line

I had written:

```
  displayedColumns: ['seqNo', 'description', 'duration'];
```

and there was:

```
displayedColumns= ['seqNo', 'description', 'duration'];
```